# Monitor /sys partition for changes

Tags: linux, display, kernel, arch-linux, inotify

inotify doesnt work on /sys and /proc file systems.
So how can I monitor a /sys partition file without polling?

Comment: Related answer:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390191/249512

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of polling?  Do you mean a sleep/check loop?  Or do you mean the `poll` system call as documented in `man 2 poll`?

According to a [2009 email from kernel developer Greg KH](http://old.nabble.com/sysfs-and-inotify-td23021094.html), the best option is to use `select`.  See `man 2 select` for details.
Note that the `poll` system call is basically the same as this.

On the other hand, the current [inotify FAQ](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=faq&lang=en) suggests it might work.

Why not try it and find out?

Comment: I think we can safely assume the OP was working from a shell and he wasn't talking about C functions. Anyway, currently it's still not working for me in /sys files (Linux 3.6.3), I only get OPEN/ACCESS events, but not changes made by the kernel.

Comment: @tokland I'm not aware of any command called `inotify`?

Comment: FWIW, `inotifywatch` from `inotify-tools` seems to work fine to count changes on `/proc/sys` on my Linux 3.5.0 system.

Comment: Mikel, I use `inotifywait` from `inotify-tools`. Can you try this in a laptop? `inotifywait -m /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status`. I get I don't get any event when this value changes (unplug/plug the battery).